# Arranging controls based on template layouts in Flex apps

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder, flexbuilder

Suppose you have a view, which **contains three control A, B and C**. The control A and B are in a HGroup, which itself is inside a VGroup with C.

Based on user interaction, I'd like to **re-arrange the controls to new layouts**. For example all three inside a VGroup. Or for example a layout, which hides A and B and maximizes C in size.

While I could hand-write the code, I'd like to use something like a **layout template**. A template, which contains placeholders for A, B and C. Give the current view, I'd like to pass the new template and the view should rearrange.

Does such a component exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not aware of such component but why you don't use states ? You can put your components in different container in each state than change the state of your parent component. I haven't tried but it should work because flex doesn't reinitialize the same component if it appears in many states.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thx! I don't believe, that this works. At least, I can't include the same components in two different states with the same ID. 'Identical' components in different state are different objects. Aren't they?

Comment: it's true that you can't have two different component with the same id on different states but you can have the same component in more than one state. If the component is always the same, just with different attribute it should work.

Comment: Great! Never used this stuff. For others reading this question: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fae.html